# Recharts Scatter Plot not plotting X axis values correctly

Tags: javascript, recharts

If you use the example in their api(https://recharts.org/en-US/api/ScatterChart) you don't get the results shown.

Here is a codesandbox of an actual example of what seems to happen: https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-issue-template-forked-rz669

The values along the X-axis just seem to appear in the order they appear in the data, and not the actual values. Furthermore, the values of the second dataset are just added onto the end of the X axis.

Is this just a bug, or am I missing something? It feels like this should be a fairly major bug, but I can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. The XAxis element property "type" defaults to "category". You need to set type="number" and it should work.